# How to treat exceptions in constructor best?

Tags: php, exception

How to treat exception in best way in construct?

**option1** - catch exception where object created:

```
class Account {
    function __construct($id){
        if(empty($id)){
            throw new My_Exception('id can\'t be empty');
        }

        // ...
    }
}

class a1 {
    function just($id){
    try {
        $account = new Account($id);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        $e->getMessage();
    }
}

class a2{
    function just($id){
    try {
        $account = new Account($id);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**option2**: catch exception inside __construct

```
class Account{
    function __construct($id){
    try{
        if(empty($id)){
            throw new My_Exception('id can\'t be empty');
        }

        // ...
    }
    catch(My_Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

Please write in which cases should be used option1 and in which should be used option2 or other better solution.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not voting to close because I'm not sure I all the details of your specific question but here is a very closely related one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685857/php-exceptions-in-classes (I personally like the alternative method @Gordon presents in his answer using `::create()` best)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, you should handle an exception thrown in a function outside this function, otherwise it won't make any sense. In regard to constructors specifically, try to avoid "new classname" as much as possible and stick to generator functions instead. For each class X, decide which class is responsible for creating objects of class X, and add a generator function to that class. This generator function is also the perfect place to handle X's constructor exceptions

```
 class AccountManager {
     function newAccount($id) {
        try {
           $obj = new Account($id);
        } catch....
           return null;
      }
 }

 // all other code uses this instead of "new Account"

 $account = $accountManager->newAccount($id);
```

Answer (score 7):

What is the purpose of throwing an exception and immediately catching it? If you want to abort a function on error but not throw an error, you should `return`.

Thus, your first code is always correct. Let the Exception bubble up.

Comment: You can't `return` from a constructor in PHP.

Comment: @DavidScherer You can return, just don't return a value (`return;`).

Comment: I'm aware you can return, but returning a value doesn't do anything (unless you call the constructor directly, which PHP allows, which has encouraged some bad programming). I mistakenly read your answer as recommending returning the error instead of throwing it.