# Catching error in construct function

Tags: php, class, object, try-catch

What is the best method for catching an error thrown by a construct function in PHP?

The method I have gone for is this but I have not seen this used anywhere else so I am unsure about it:

```
try{
    $connection = new test(/*Some Params*/);
}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',$e->getMessage(),"\n";
}
```

Any advice much appreciated, thanks

Comment: @ManseUK How did you find that!!! I searched everywhere! :-) I obviously typed in the wrong keywords!

Comment: I googled `site:stackoverflow.com catch exception on constructor php` :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the purposes of other people reading this question, it is a duplicate of:

[How to treat exceptions in constructor best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646157/how-to-treat-exceptions-in-constructor-best)

It appears that the method I have mentioned above in my question is indeed correct.